# multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please explain what is the meaning of

```
foreach ($toplist['children'] as $subkey => $subname)
```

and where the children come from. I'm confused.

Answer (score 4):

Basically `$toplist` is an array of values. One of those values has been called `'children'`.

In this case, the value at position `'children'` is itself an array.

Your line of code is telling the computer to loop over each of the values inside the 'children' array and extract the key and value.

`$subkey` is the key, `$subname` is the name.

In other words, `$toplist['children'][$subkey] == $subvalue`

Answer (score 0):

The other elements are coming from the **$toplist['children']** array which you got to figure out where it is coming from since you have not put in all the needed code for the question. See this about [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) machenism to learn more about it.

> his simply gives an easy way to
>   iterate over arrays. foreach works
>   only on arrays, and will issue an
>   error when you try to use it on a
>   variable with a different data type or
>   an uninitialized variable.

php.net